# Jquery div in iframe hide and text show

Tags: jquery

Jquery div in iframe hide and text show

```
<iframe></iframe> - hide
<div>Offline mode!</div> - show?
```

Comment: Please add more info so that we can help

Comment: I want body tag in iframes hide and instead of text show : )

Comment: So, u want to manipulate iframe's elements?

Or want to hide the iframe?

Answer (score 1):

If u want to manipulate iframe's elements, then u can have a great support from ***[this tutorial](http://seriouscoding.com/2009/05/22/how-to-access-an-iframe-with-jquery/)***.

If u want to hide the iframe, then here is a simple example is given for u-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("iframe").hide();

    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("iframe").hide();
        $("p").show();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("iframe").show();
        $("p").hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/demo_iframe.htm" width="200" height="200"></iframe>

<p>Offline Mode</p>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
```

### Re-

I am not clear about your requirement yet, so I had to answer in this 2 way.

Comment: Thanks, but no hide and show button.

If hide it instead iframe show warning

Comment: Do it with jQuery, can u please explain what is your need of this? I am not still clear about your requirement. If u clear, I can help

Comment: Actually this image don't help. Please add a demo code or an example senerio